# Type of contractor for basement egress doors?

Tags: concrete, basement, foundation

I'm interested in getting some quotes to have Bilco-style doors installed in an existing house. I have checked the Bilco website, and no listed contractors in my area (Wisconsin).

I can find contractors that do egress windows, and concrete companies that pour foundations. But whom should I be looking for to get this done? Just find a GC of some sort to handle the details?

Comment: Can we assume that you'll need a foundation extension created around the entrance, or is this simply a door replacement?

Comment: Have you actually contacted any of the contractors you've identified to ask if they'll do this work? If they say no, have you asked _them_ for recommendations? I doubt you'll find "Bilco door installer" as a category of contractor, but someone who is willing to do the work, and that could be just about anyone.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps try this business. https://www.infinityroofing.com/Roof/Brands/BilcoHatches. I found them on the web.

Comment: Link only answers are highly discouraged here. Secondarily questions asking for product recommendations and answers providing them provide little value for the general audience coming here seeking information and are thus considered off topic.